# How to add +1 to variable name in a for loop?

Tags: python, django

'nearestzipcodes' is a list containing 5 items (a key/value).  I'm trying to just take each value and assign it to account.nearestzip1 through 5.  The code below I'm guessing will not work, because it is assigning all 5 each time for each item in nearestzipcodes.

How can I correct this for loop?  Do I just add a +1 at the end of nearestzip and delete the next 4 duplicate lines?

```
for i in nearestzipcodes:
    account.nearestzip1 = i.values()
    account.nearestzip2 = i.values()
    account.nearestzip3 = i.values()
    account.nearestzip4 = i.values()
    account.nearestzip5 = i.values()
```

Comment: Replace account.nearestzip1-5 with a list.

Answer (score 0):

You can use setattr, like this:

```
for i,v in enumerate(nearestzipcodes,1):
     setattr(account, 'nearestzip' + str(i), v.values())
```

This is a strange design choice, however. The real question that begs attention is why not use some kind of container inside of `account` to hold the `nearestzip`s?

While setattr should serve your purpose directly, its use is usually more reserved for cases where dynamic attribute access is unavoidable; it incurs extra performance costs and makes code less readable. Only use it if you must. In my opinion, your situation is yelling for a `list` attribute inside of `account`. You'll get the same result by indexing:

```
account.nearestzip[0]
account.nearestzip[1]
account.nearestzip[2]
...
```

Comment: So like put a list inside of my django model?

Comment: @donnaloia I am not familiar with _django_ and can't really advise you on a course. If these attributes somehow are part of the API, then I suppose you could fall back on `setattr`. You'll have to make that call.

Answer (score 0):

each account.nearestzipcode is a django formfield entry, so I don't know how to replace it with a list.  I would appreciate an example of this.

In any case, since there are only 5 items in the list, I guess i can just do:

```
account.nearestzip1 = nearestzipcodes[0]
account.nearestzip2 = nearestzipcodes[1]
account.nearestzip3 = nearestzipcodes[2]
account.nearestzip4 = nearestzipcodes[3]
account.nearestzip5 = nearestzipcodes[4]
```